# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer frame in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to get the video output on my screen in Swift. But the screen stays completely white. I found this tutorial in [ObjC](http://dannygtech.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/custom-camera-on-ios-avcapturesession-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-tutorial/) and I followed it (only in Swift style syntax).

In there there is a line `previewLayer.frame = myView.bounds;`

But the field `.frame` seems to be read only in swift. And I think this might be why I don't see anything on the screen.

How can I set the frame for the previewLayer in Swift?

Comment: `frame` is not read-only in Swift. What leads you to think that?

Comment: Forgot to unwrap the argument, my bad :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see three points in that tutorial where you could end up not displaying the preview, and thus getting a white screen. Below are the Obj-C and Swift counterparts.

1) You might have missed adding the input to the capture session:

```
// [session addInput:input];
session.addInput(input)
```

2) You might not have initialized the preview layer's bounds to that of your view controller:

```
// UIView *myView = self.view;
// previewLayer.frame = myView.bounds;
previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
```

3) You might not have added the preview layer as a sublayer of your view:

```
// [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```